# How do I send parameters with an HTTP post request in Flutter?

Tags: http, flutter

Previously I was able to send HTTP requests using Retrofit in my Android project.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<SignIn> loginUserWithoutKeyTest(@Field("User_Name") String name,
                                     @Field("Password") String password);
```

Now I am converting this to Flutter. How can I make this HTTP request?

Follwing is my code but it doesnt work. Could someone please let me know the correct way

```
 final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lk/login',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
        <String, String>{'User_name': '876378499', 'Password': '123456'}));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  String data = response.body;
  print(data);
  var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

  return decodedData;
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just removed JasonEncod function and made as following.Then it worked

```
Future<dynamic> auliatestlogin() async {
final http.Response response = await http
    .post('https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/login', headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}, body: <String, String>{
  'User_Name': '077111',
  'Password': 'saman123'
});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  String data = response.body;
  print(data);
  var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

  return decodedData;
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
```

}